# Dspace XMLUI discovery messages

Tags: dspace, discovery

I'm working with Dspace 6.3. I added some customize filters in the Dspace Discovery module. They are working in the sense that they return results, but I am having some problems with the visualization of the filters in the advanced search box and in the sidebar. The message in the sidebar looks like this

xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.AdvancedSearch.type_type

And the message in the advanced search box looks like this

xmlui.ArtifactBrowser.SimpleSearch.filter.type

I understand that in order to fix this problem, I have to modify and move the messages.xml file of the src directory, and to run de mvn package and ant update. I tried to do those things and nothing happened. I´m not quite sure I am modifiying the correct file, so I searched the src diectory for all the messages.xml files that existed. This was the result

```
root@DspaceDTB:/home/grisel-pascual/SRC/dspace-6.3-src-release# find -iname "mes                                                                                       sages.xml"
./dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/XMLWorkflow/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/SwordClient/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/modules/xmlui/target/war/work/org.dspace/dspace-xmlui/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/modules/xmlui/target/war/work/org.dspace/dspace-xmlui/WEB-INF/classes/a                                                                                       spects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/modules/xmlui/target/war/work/org.dspace/dspace-xmlui/WEB-INF/classes/a                                                                                       spects/XMLWorkflow/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/modules/xmlui/target/war/work/org.dspace/dspace-xmlui/WEB-INF/classes/a                                                                                       spects/SwordClient/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/modules/xmlui/target/xmlui-6.3/i18n/messages.xml
./dspace/target/dspace-installer/webapps/xmlui/i18n/messages.xml
```

I consulted the wiki, and the recommendation was this:

> Internationalization Discovery has its own messages.xml file, located
> at
> dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml.
> To add your own labels for new fields and facets in a Maven overlay,
> copy this file to
> dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml
> and modify this file. Alternatively, you may add them to the main
> messages.xml file. Same goes for translations - it's encouraged to
> submit a single messages_XX.xml file including messages from all the
> separate messages.xml files in DSpace.

But in my directory, I can't find the second route (dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml)

Any help with this issue would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> But in my directory, I can't find the second route (dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml)

Well, it is stated in the wiki that you included:

> Internationalization Discovery has its own messages.xml file, located at dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml. To add your own labels for new fields and facets in a Maven overlay, copy this file to dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery/i18n/messages.xml and modify this file.

In other words, if you can't find it under the modules directory, you have to 'recreate' that path and copy the `messages.xml`.

If you modified the main `messages.xml` to include your custom label for Discovery and after mvn and ant update, nothing happens, did you try clearing your browser cache or maybe just a hard refresh of your browser? What you're seeing might be a cached page.

There is also an option in the XMLUI webui control panel to clear the cache immediately which can be accessed from `/admin/panel?tab=Java Information&clearcache=true`

Comment: I been trying, but still can't fix the issue. I did the cache clear that you recommended.
I think i might be doing the ant update wrong. The wiki states that I have to go to: ```cd [dspace-source]/dspace/target/dspace-[version]-build.dir/```
But in my console, when I get to ```[dspace-source]/dspace/target/```, there is no folder named ```dspace-[version]-build.dir/```, instead there are two folders named ```archive-temp``` and ```dspace-installer```.
Where should I run the ant update?

Comment: You should run it under `dspace-installer`, please see [Step 8](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-Installation) where it states: `cd [dspace-source]/dspace/target/dspace-installer` then run `ant fresh_install` or you can run `ant update`.